# how to delete a record from ORMLITE?

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to delete a record from ORMLite Database I can delete a record by id using  as below

```
@Override
public void Delete(int id) throws SQLException {
    this.dao.deleteById(id);
}
```

but what if I have to delete a record from same table not by id but by name or any other field
I want something like

```
public void Deletefromcanteen(String name,MealType mealtype) {
    this.dao.deletebyName(name);
}
```

what query should i write using querybuilder to delete a record where name = name and mealtype = say (lunch)

I tried something like this in my databasehelper class

```
public  void deletefromcanteen(int id, String mealtype) {
    try {
        Dao<CanteenLog, Integer> canteenDao = getCanteen();
        DeleteBuilder<CanteenLog, Integer> deleteBuilder = canteenDao
                .deleteBuilder();
        deleteBuilder.where().eq("user_id", id).and().eq("meal", mealtype);
        canteenDao.delete(deleteBuilder.prepare());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
deleteBuilder.where().eq("FIELD_NAME", arg);
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

Update:

For example :

```
//Get helper
DatabaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(App.getContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);

//get dao
Dao dao = helper.getDao(YOUR_CLASS.class);

//delete elements from table in field by arg
DeleteBuilder<CanteenLog, Integer> deleteBuilder = dao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where().eq("FIELD_NAME", arg);
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

Good luck!

Comment: @llya Demidove can you please elaborate the imlementation how it should be

Answer (score 0):

To save building a query, you can do a select to find the ID, then do a delete by ID.  Thsi will be straightforward if you already have the select query set up for this table.

Comment: I don't have select query for this table again first i'll have to build select query isn't it

Answer (score 0):

It can be done also like that

```
DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getDao(YourObject.class).delete(yourObjectInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, you will need to do something like this instead since the type inference is not currently working correctly for the fluent syntax:

```
val deleteBuilder = dao.deleteBuilder()
            val where = deleteBuilder.where().eq("address", address)
            deleteBuilder.setWhere(where)
            deleteBuilder.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an instance of the object (or object list) you want to delete, just do :

```
//Get helper
DatabaseHelper helper = 
    OpenHelperManager.getHelper(App.getContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);
// delete 'em !
helper.getDao(YourObject.class).delete(yourObjectInstance);
```

If you don't have the instance to delete or you want to do it SQL way(!):

```
//Get helper
DatabaseHelper helper = 
    OpenHelperManager.getHelper(App.getContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);

//get dao
Dao dao = helper.getDao(YOUR_CLASS.class);

//delete elements from table in field by arg
DeleteBuilder<CanteenLog, Integer> deleteBuilder = dao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where().eq("FIELD_NAME", "FIELD_VALUE");
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

If you need a more complicated `Where` logic, then use `deleteBuilder.where().or()` or `deleteBuilder.where().and()` to add more constraints.