# how to retrieve a record from ORMLITE?

Tags: android, ormlite

Similar to my previous question [how to delete a record from ormlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108195/how-to-delete-a-record-from-ormlite) Again I can retrieve record by Id as

```
public BO Retrieve(int id) throws SQLException {
        TEntity entity = this.dao.queryForId(id);

        return getBizObject(entity);
    }
```

but how to go about retrieve record not by id but by any other field like user_id?

I want to know about query builder for retrieve a record

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a RTFM answer.  The [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `QueryBuider` is well documented with some good examples:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder

To quote from the manual, something like the following will query for a particular field.

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.where().eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty");
List<Account> accountList = queryBuilder.query();
```

The [javadocs for `QueryBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html) are online and the [`Where` object javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html) which you use to define the various comparisons also provide good information.  There's also a section in the manual of [building more complex queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries).

Also, if you are just querying for a single field then [DAO has a queryForEq(...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryForEq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method that does the `QueryBuilder` stuff for you.

Btw, it is recommended, if you are referring to the name of the field that you define it in a `public static final` constant:

```
public class Account {
    public static final String PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME = "password"; 
    ...
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME)
    private String password;
```

Comment: Gray: I've seen people declare QueryBuilder<Account, String> or QueryBuilder<Account, Integer>. What does it mean to use String vs Integer?

Comment: I was going to point you to the javadocs but they are missing for that.  The 2nd parameter is the type of the ID field.  This allows stuff like `dao.queryForid(id)` and other methods to validate the type of the id @dannyroa.

Comment: Ah. That's great. That explains why my queryForId is always Integer. I'm trying to use String as my ID but queryForId is insisting on an Integer.