# Android ORMLite cannot delete object

Tags: java, android, ormlite

In the same Activity I delete the **Bookmark** object then I try to query it from DB, it still there? This is my code to delete and query:

```
    public void removeBookmark(Bookmark bookmark) {
        try {
            getHelper().getBookmarkDao().deleteById(bookmark.getId());
            getHelper().getBookmarkDao().clearObjectCache();


//            DeleteBuilder<Bookmark, String> deleteBuilder = getHelper().getBookmarkDao().deleteBuilder();
//            deleteBuilder.where().eq("id", bookmark.getId());
//            PreparedDelete<Bookmark> preparedQuery = deleteBuilder.prepare();
//            getHelper().getBookmarkDao().delete(preparedQuery);
            List<Bookmark> lst = listBookmarks(bookmark.getIsbn());
            LOGD(TAG, "removeBookmark count: " + lst.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<Bookmark> listBookmarks(String id) {
        List<Bookmark> bookmarks = new ArrayList<Bookmark>();
        try {
            QueryBuilder<Bookmark, String> queryBuilder = getHelper().getBookmarkDao().queryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.where().eq("id", id);
            PreparedQuery<Bookmark> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
            bookmarks = getHelper().getBookmarkDao().query(preparedQuery);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bookmarks;
    }
```

I also `clearObjectCache` but nothing happen.

This is the version of my ORMLite: `compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'`

Comment: Also visited this page but not work at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108195/how-to-delete-a-record-from-ormlite

Comment: Sorry, it's my wrong, I'm using ORMLite this is the version `compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'`. So what different between them and the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using ORMLite or GreenDAO.  They are separate things.

I think you are having a problem because you are deleting using the `bookmark` id:

```
getHelper().getBookmarkDao().deleteById(bookmark.getId());
```

But then listing the bookmark by isbn:

```
List<Bookmark> lst = listBookmarks(bookmark.getIsbn());
```

If they aren't the same field then there's your problem.

Comment: I'm using ORMLite, actually `List<Bookmark> lst = listBookmarks(bookmark.getId());` but still there. However I resolved my problem by myself. The reason is some missing id when I inserted object, then I need to uninstall app to clean old data. Thanks for your idea

Comment: Can you explain more the two separate things or give me reference to know more, what is the better choice between them?

Comment: I'll leave it to you do the research there @tbbt.